# About Dependencies

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

In the absence of internet connection for the present, I am trying to use apt-offline. When I execute the order in terminal I get "ERROR: FATAL: Something is wrong with the apt system." I have been told that this problem is probably a dependencies problem.

So I run "apt-get -f install" and there appeared some dependencies. I tried to install some of them to be, then, able to use apt-offline.

But, the problem is, it seems even more dependencies appeared. To the question then:

Question: Is there a way to "kill" all those dependencies? To somehow maybe get reed of them and be able to use the apt-offline?

Thank you.

NOTE: These are the orders:

1)

```
kwstas@debian:~$ su -c  'apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig'
Password: 

Generating database of files that are needed for an update.

Generating database of files that are needed for an upgrade.
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
ERROR: FATAL: Something is wrong with the apt system.
```

2)Then I run and I get:

```
kwstas@debian:~$ su -c 'apt-get -f install'
Password: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common dvdauthor freepats genisoimage
  growisofs libexempi3 libfftw3-double3 libfluidsynth1 libgme0 libgmime-2.6-0
  libgtkglext1 libiptcdata0 libmediaart-1.0-0 libmimic0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0
  libmms0 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmpg123-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libmusicbrainz5-1
  libnautilus-extension1a libofa0 libopenal-data libopenal1
  libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core2.4
  libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4
  libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4
  libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libsbc1
  libsoundtouch0 libspandsp2 libsrtp0 libtbb2 libtotem-plparser18
  libtracker-sparql-1.0-0 libunistring0 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0
  libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libzbar0 sound-juicer wodim
Suggested packages:
  vcdimager libdvdcss2 tracker readom cdrkit-doc libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev
  srtp-utils gstreamer1.0-lame gstreamer1.0-plugins-really-bad
Recommended packages:
  yelp
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  brasero-cdrkit dvdauthor freepats genisoimage growisofs libexempi3
  libfftw3-double3 libfluidsynth1 libgme0 libgmime-2.6-0 libgtkglext1
  libiptcdata0 libmediaart-1.0-0 libmimic0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0
  libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmpg123-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libmusicbrainz5-1
  libnautilus-extension1a libofa0 libopenal-data libopenal1
  libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core2.4
  libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4
  libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4
  libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libsbc1
  libsoundtouch0 libspandsp2 libsrtp0 libtbb2 libtotem-plparser18
  libtracker-sparql-1.0-0 libunistring0 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0
  libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libzbar0 wodim
The following packages will be upgraded:
  brasero brasero-common sound-juicer
3 upgraded, 51 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 43.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 55.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

3)The rest is when I reply yes:

```
Err http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/debian/ jessie/main brasero i386 3.11.4-1.1
  Could not resolve 'ftp.cc.uoc.gr'
Err http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/debian/ jessie/main brasero-common all 3.11.4-1.1
  Could not resolve 'ftp.cc.uoc.gr'
Err http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/debian/ jessie/main libgmime-2.6-0 i386 2.6.20-1+b1
  Could not resolve 'ftp.cc.uoc.gr'
Err http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/linux/debian/ jessie/main libquvi-scripts all 0.4.21-2
  Could not resolve 'ftp.cc.uoc.gr'
```

.
.
. and it goes until:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: "there appeared some dependencies". Please paste exact commands and also the results of those commands if you want actual answers. To quote someone who once replied to me on IRC. "We left our crystal balls at home".  And no, you don't "kill" dependencies. You satisfy them. Just to be clear, does this computer have an internet connection?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are correct about posting the exact commands but I think I have found the solution-it' s the same with your comment: I cannot kill them.I have to satisfy them. I didn't post them because they are a lot. I will make an edit in a minute.

Comment: @FaheemMitha      I've made the edit.

Comment: As I see it I don't think there is a solution until I find an internet connection to fix them. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get -f install`. And yes, of course you need to use `apt-offline` on an internet connection.